# How to calculate MEAN of exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, average, exponential-function

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac15 e^{(-\frac15x)}, x>0 \\
0, \text{elsewhere}\\ \end{cases}$

How to calculate $E[(X+5)]$ and $E[(X+5)^2]$ ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know what $E[X]$ is?

Comment: $$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{(x+5)\exp(\frac{-x}{5})}{5}$$

Comment: What did you try and what is STOPPING you?

Comment: I know $E[X]$ means the mean/expected value of $f(x)$

Comment: I know $E[X]$ = 5 but I've no idea about $E[(X+5)^2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:  for $E[X+5]$ use the linearity of expectation.  What is $E[5]$?

For $E[(X+5)^2]$ you can go back to the definition $$E[(X+5)^2]=\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{(x+5)^2\exp(\frac{-x}{5})\; dx}{5}$$  or you can expand out $E[(X+5)^2]=E[X^2]+2E[X]E[5]+E[5^2]$

Comment: Is $E[X] = \frac1\lambda $? Then $E[X] = 5$.
Can we use the similar method to find out $E[(x+5)^2]$ ?

Comment: Yes, $E[X]=5$  The way you find that (if you don't look it up) is the integral Inquest gave without the +5.  The integral in my answer is the same method for $E[(X+5)^2]$  Can you do it?

Comment: Sorry. Can you show the steps why $E[(X+5)^2]=E[X^2]+2E[X]+E[5^2]$?

Comment: Why it's not  $E[(X+5)^2]=E[X^2]+10E[X]+E[5^2]$  but  $+2E[X]$?

Comment: @Rick:  You are right, I dropped the $E[5]$.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that
$$
\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-u} \, du = 2,
$$
then you can write
$$
\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x/5}\, \frac{dx}{5} = 5^2 \int_0^\infty \left(\frac x 5\right)^2 e^{-x/5} \, \frac{dx}{5} = 5^2\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-u} \, du = 5^2\cdot 2.
$$
That gets you $E(X^2)$.  And $E((X+5)^2) = E(X^2) + 10E(X) + 5^2$, etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more on $E((X+5)2)=E(X2)+10E(X)+5$?
I'm quite confused.

Comment: Why it's not  $E[(X+5)^2]=E[X^2]+10E[X]+E[5^2]$ but $+5$?

Comment: Sorry --- typo: It's $5^2$.